# Fit vs Fill assets in container

Tags: html, css

I have to display a bunch of images to fit the container. Does anyone know how to do that? Instead of fill it should Fit. Just like you do it in photoshop where you can choose to fit in the container.

Comment: Explain what you mean by fit like in photoshop. These terms sounds like auto-fit and auto-fill functions in CSS grid-templates properties. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns